# How to swap databases in ArangoDB for zero downtime on a production server

Tags: arangodb, database-restore

I have a production server with a single ArangoDB database containing large collections (millions of edges and tens of thousand nodes). Every week it gets regenerated on a different server and then the updated database get pushed to the production server using arangodump. The problem is that the copy takes about 1h, during which the production server is not really usable. Is there a solution to avoid any downtime ?

With MySQL to update table1, I can fill table1_tmp and then switch tables with an atomic operation:

`RENAME TABLE` table1`to`table1_old`,` table1_tmp`TO`table1`;`

However I did not find an equivalent in ArangoDB

Comment: I would toggle between two database names and have your main application switch to the different database at prescribed times after it validates that the database is ready to consume.

This isn't an ArangoDB specific thing, rather it's something you can do with any brand of database.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but according to https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1243 it is not possible with ArangoDB.

Comment: We would solve this using our internal DNS server with a low TTL, don't copy the regenerated data to the correct server, just let the host-name move between servers.

Comment: @YvesRenier I probably didn't explain it right. If you have a Node.js application (or something else) that consumes your database, then have it connect to your production server to the 'prod_a' database (defined in your connection string). Then next week you have your Node.js application change to the database 'prod_b' where the new data exists. Then the next week you move back to 'prod_a'. You then restore your weekly data to the correct database at the correct time. If you store persistent data in your database you'll need to split that out. What technology do you connect to the DB with?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, instead of moving the database I will just modify a file which indicate what database to use.